# resize gif animation in android

Tags: android, resize, gif

I want to resize a gif animation so that 1 of my button fit on the screen. I am using WebView for gif animation. When I am inserting a image button it is not getting displayed. Please Help.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context=".Activity_B" > 

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:src="@drawable/back" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: code please so that we can understand what you have tried .

Comment: Update your code and Webview in android doesn't support gif animation.your need to write your own implementation for gif animation

Comment: WebView in android supports gif animation. I have done it. And it dont even need any imageview, we can directly put the gif animation's path and its done. I just want to display a image button on the screen but i guess the screen is being occupied by the gif animation fully so can anyone tell me how to bring the image button at the front of the animation so that it is noticable and clickable..

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity_B" >

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />
    
</RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you define your WebView? See if this works for you:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context=".Activity_B" > 

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:src="@drawable/back" /> 

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit 1:**

Let's say the layout file with `RelativeLayout` and `ImageButton` is called `mainLayout.xml`. 
Do the following:

```
View mainView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mainLayout, null);

RelativeLayout rlContainer = (RelativeLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.rlContainer);

GIFWebView view = new GIFWebView (this, "file:///android_asset/imageedit_ball.gif");

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams wvParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

wvParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.imageButton1);

rlContainer.addView(view, wvParams);

setContentView(mainView);
```

Give your RelativeLayout an id:

```
android:id="@+id/rlContainer"

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context=".Activity_B"
    android:id="@+id/rlContainer" > 

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:src="@drawable/back" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i dont need to insert webview as such. the gif animation is getting played. but I am unable to display a button which i need to have it on the animation. I tried this but not working.

Comment: @Meghs Can you post how and where you add `WebView` to the layout? Can you post that part of the code?

Comment: GIFWebView view = new GIFWebView
    (this, "file:///android_asset/imageedit_ball.gif");
  
  
  setContentView(view); 

where GIFWebView is a class which extends WebView..   

    public class GIFWebView extends WebView  
 {

 public GIFWebView(Context context, String path) 
  {
  super(context);
  loadUrl(path);
 
  }
 }

Comment: Can I add gif animation in a window?

Comment: @Meghs Take a look at **Edit 1** above. It'll fix your problem.

Comment: But I am unable to insert on click listener on the image button. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Meghs Add `ImageButton imageButton1 = (ImageButton) mainView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1); imageButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {.....})` before `seContentView(mainView);`.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i lock touch event when the gif animation is playing. n thn unlock it again when the animation loop is completed?

Comment: @Meghs `Can you tell me how can i lock touch event when the gif animation is playing. n thn unlock it again when the animation loop is completed?`. <<< Hi. Please start a new question for this. If someone searches for this issue, they will not find this page.

Comment: I have. This is the link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287384/lock-ontouch-listener?noredirect=1#comment26828837_18287384

Answer (score 0):

Please Add Relative layout and then put that 1st button and 2nd webview to fit in relative layout .

Comment: i tried all the possible combinations but unable to solve the problem.

Comment: The code is already written above. Its the same. Can anyone tell me how to bring a button in front on gif animation?