# Lock ontouch listener

Tags: android, touch-event

I want to lock the ontouch listener when the animation is being played. this is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {


 boolean gifIsPlaying;
 long PLAYING_TIME_OF_GIF = 111;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    GIFWebView view = new GIFWebView
            (this, "file:///android_asset/imageedit_ball.gif");


    gifIsPlaying = true;

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            gifIsPlaying = false;
        }
    }, PLAYING_TIME_OF_GIF);


    setContentView(view);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }       

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (gifIsPlaying) {
        // No response to touch events
    } else {
        // Respond to touch events
        GIFWebView view1 = new GIFWebView
                (this, "file:///android_asset/imageedit_ball.gif");

        gifIsPlaying = true;

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                gifIsPlaying = false;
            }
        }, PLAYING_TIME_OF_GIF);

        setContentView(view1);
    }

    // Consume touch event
    return true;
}

}
```

I have tried to implement ontouch within ontouch but no use. I want to temperory lock ontouch till the gif animation completes a loop. Please help.

Comment: use a boolean variable inside the onTouch to execute the code...you can use a TimerTask to wait for some time and switch the boolean variable.

Comment: public boolean isAnimationOn = false; public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    if (isAnimationOn)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}  I tried using this but not working

Comment: provide the proper code implementation that u had used..

Comment: @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
   
   if (loaded) {
    
    return false;
    
   }
   else {
    
     GIFWebView view1 = new GIFWebView
             (this, "file:///android_asset/imageedit_ball.gif");
     setContentView(view1);
     view1.setOnTouchListener(this);
   }
   
  }
  
  return true;
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following *if* you know the GIF's running time:

Declare a global boolean variable:

```
boolean gifIsPlaying;
long PLAYING_TIME_OF_GIF = ???;
```

After creating and adding GIFWebView to your activity's view, set `gifIsPlaying` to `true`. Delayed-post a Runnable to set `gifIsPlaying` to `false` after `PLAYING_TIME_OF_GIF`:

```
gifIsPlaying = true;

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        gifIsPlaying = false;
    }
}, PLAYING_TIME_OF_GIF);
```

`PLAYING_TIME_OF_GIF` will be a `long` variable.

Inside your onTouch(View, MotionEvent):

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (gifIsPlaying) {
        // No response to touch events
    } else {
        // Respond to touch events
        GIFWebView view1 = new GIFWebView
                (this, "file:///android_asset/imageedit_ball.gif");

        gifIsPlaying = true;

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                gifIsPlaying = false;
            }
        }, PLAYING_TIME_OF_GIF);

        setContentView(view1);
    }

    // Consume touch event
    return true;
}
```

If this approach works for you, consider creating a `Handler` once and reusing it. Same goes for the `Runnable`.

I don't think there's any other way to solve this problem. There certainly isn't a callback method to inform you that the GIF has run its course.

Comment: Its not working, Actually at first the touch event is taking place but later the touch event is not working.

Comment: @Meghs Can you post your whole activity in the question above?

Comment: @Meghs `Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, long)`: the `long` argument is delay time in milliseconds. So, `111` would translate to `0.111 seconds`. If your GIF's playing time is `111` seconds, define `PLAYING_TIME_OF_GIF` equal to `111000`.

Comment: how can i calculate the exact gif time of the animation? because i dont know the exact time and i want to catch the time so that i can give the exact time to PLAYING_TIME_OF_GIF

Comment: @Meghs Generally, GIFs are looped to play endlessly. So, its a bit strange when you say `I want to lock the ontouch listener when the animation is being played`. Because, the GIF will play endlessly. In any case. If this is just one GIF that you need to play, use a stopwatch and time it yourself. Use the duration to set `PLAYING_TIME_OF_GIF`. Other than that, I'm not sure what you can do.

Comment: okay But the animation which I am playing is already a single loop. so i have taken the ontouch listener. and everything is working fine. All i need is to catch the time of the animation and as the animation is of a single loop ill b able to do that too. Just wanted to know what is the method i should use.

Comment: @Meghs Correct. Just get the duration by timing the animation yourself, and the approach I have proposed should work just fine.